# How do I can install libxcb-render-unil0?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, 32-bit, cad

I need libxcb-render-unil0 for running DraftSight™ 32x ver under my 64x os. I was trying to install it by a terminal or Synaptic Package Manager but it I didn't succeed in this.

```
root@nazar-Aspire-5720Z:/home/nazar# sudo apt-get install libxcb-render-unil0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libxcb-render-unil0
```

I just can't understand what's wrong. Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with the missing dependency, but on a 32-bit system. 
Here is the missing file> http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/i386/libxcb-render-util0/download

Also, you might want to check [this](http://linuxaideddesign.blogspot.com/2011/10/draftsight-on-ubuntu-1110.html) for further insrtructions.

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy this right?

```
root@nazar-Aspire-5720Z:/home/nazar# sudo apt-get install libxcb-render-unil0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libxcb-render-unil0
```

It seems that you've misspelt `libxcb-render-util0`.  Note that it's `util` not `unil`.

Once you've fixed that, `apt-get install libxcb-render-util0` will install the version for the default architecture.  On the amd64 builds of Ubuntu, that's x86-64, which is not what you want.

You want the i386 version, which you can install with

```
sudo apt-get install libxcb-render-util0:i386
```